# AWS SAM: How to initialize S3Client credentials from a lambda function handler

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

I am building an HTTP API using [sam local start-api](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-cli-command-reference-sam-local-start-api.html). Each endpoint of this API is mapped to a lambda handler I have written in Javascript code.

One of these lambda handlers requires to download and upload files from S3, for which I am using this [`S3Client`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/index.html) from `@aws-sdk/client-s3`. I have tried to initialize such client as follows:

```
const s3Client = new S3Client({
    region: "eu-west-1"
});
```

expecting that it reads the credentials from my `~/.aws/credentials` file, but it does not. All operations via this client fail due to lack of permissions.

I would like to know what is the correct way of using this S3Client from within a lambda handler that I am testing locally using `sam local`.

Comment: Lack of permissions != lack of credentials. What exactly is the issue?

Comment: If I hard-code the credentials when initializing the S3 (snippet above) I can, for example, generate a pre-signed URL that works: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/s3-example-creating-buckets.html#s3-create-presigendurl-get

However, if these crendentials are not specified hard-coding them, any pre-signed URL generated is invalid. It will throw a "The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records" error. This is just one possible scenario when using the S3 client.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not using the default profile in your AWS credentials file, Sam CLI commands have a `--profile` option to specify which profile to use.

For example:

```
sam local start-api --profile my_profile
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-cli-command-reference-sam-local-start-api.html